# Checking for characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I would like to check for a string that MUST have **numbers** and COULD have **space**, **-** and **+** (optionally). Anything else should not be allowed.

I tried it with the following code but I think there must be something wrong with my Regex:

```
$phone = 2454212154;
if (!preg_match('[\s0-9+-]', $phone)) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Use  `'~[\s0-9+-]~'` (or `'~^[\s0-9+-]+$~'` if the string can only contain the allowed chars).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, that helped me a lot!